# How is important libfam and gam_server?

Tags: cygwin

I uses Cygwin Emacs w32. I found out that Emacs started `gam_server.exe`:

https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg153120.html

```
bash# apt-cyg depends emacs-w32 | grep gamin
170:emacs-w32 > emacs > libglib2.0_0 > libfam0 > gamin
1533:emacs-w32 > libMagickCore6_2 > libcairo2 > libglib2.0_0 > libfam0 > gamin
```

I am not sure if Emacs need libfam0 via  libglib2.0_0... Can someone confirm this?

I removed `gamin` package, but dependency to `gamin` is "required" so on next update I need to repeat manual steps to remove that scam again. With missing `gamin` in Emacs console:

```
failed to find gam_server
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/fam-user/fam-
```

`gam_server` looks like bloatware to me.

I don't understand if that file tracking server is using Windows API or Cygwin developers ported Linux `intofy` API... Because otherwise it useless.

Should I open Emacs bug (Windows build uses `libfam`)? Should Cygwin build adjusted with come options to disable `libfam`/`gamin`?

Comment: This is necessary for file watching with the `gfilenotify` backend.  The `w32notify` backend is probably picked by the native windows build.

Comment: @wasamasa `file-notify--library` is `gfilenotify`. and `(featurep 'gfilenotify)` and `(member "gfilenotify.o" build-files)`.